# Setup.py is not including other than py file

Tags: python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    setup(name='cool_lib',
          version='0.1',
          packages=['cool_lib'],`enter code here`
          #packages=find_packages(where='src'),
          package_data={'cool_lib.foldera': ['*'],'cool_lib.folderb': ['*']},
          include_package_data=True,
 )

folder structure

cool_lib
 setup.py
 **init**.py
 MANIFEST
 foldera
    **init**
    test1.text
foldera
    **init**
    test1.bat

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGN1E.png)

Comment: cool_lib
 setup
 MANIFEST
 foldera
 __init__
 test1.text
foldera
 __init__
 test1.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project needs to be structured with `package_name/__init__.py` in the root (same dir as setup.py)

EDIT: add manifest.in file with: `include package_name/data.txt` for example and in setup.py add `include_package_data=True`

```
project_root
    package_name
        __init__.py
        data.txt <--- data file
        ...other_scripts.py
    manifest.in
    setup.py
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='package_name',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['package_name'],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    include_package_data=True
)
```

manifest.in:

```
include package_name/data.txt
```

When I run `pip install .` in a virtual environment it adds data.txt to the installed package:

[image]

Comment: my problem is not .py file im able to package them using sdist command  ,i want to include any text or any .bat or xml or json file type which is being excluded

Comment: Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

This post also worked like charm it ideally zipped entire folder

https://github.com/tulsawebdevs/django-multi-gtfs